# SDK API namespacing design

Tags: javascript, node.js

I like to implement like a namespacing something like this as example:

```
const { SMS } = require('./custom-sdk')

const list = SMS.List();
let data = list.getData("ABC");

console.log(data)
```

I am completely stuck how to implement this, what do I need to do design this kind of API methods.

I have tried like this would which would be in `custom-sdk.js` file:

```
module.exports = {
    SMS: function() {
        // ...
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would something like the following nesting work?

```
module.exports = {
    SMS: {
        List: function() {
            return {
                getData: function(arg) {
                    // get that data
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Which I think would allow you to do `SMS.List().getData('ABC')`.  That said, this seems overly nested, unless you just simplified it for the SO question. I would suggest to only use functions when necessary (to take an argument or to instantiate a service) and prefer just a plain object when possible:

```
module.exports = {
    SMS: {
        List: {
            getData: function(arg) {
                // get that data
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Then I need `getData` method in `List` function? Like `const list = SMS.List();
let data = list.getData("ABC");`

Comment: If you have idea how to reduce nesting and improve the name-spacing design? There will be multiple services like SMS, IDS, etc. And each service will have a few modules like `Products`, `Payment`. In each module there will be a couple of functions like getData(), Insert()